# Get all documents from Couchbase bucket

Tags: java, database, couchbase, sql++

I am writing Couchbase DAO using Java API. I store all documents for one entity in particular bucket. I wonder what is the best way to get all documents from this bucket?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**First**: do you plan to store each entity type in their own buckets? That will probably not work in the long run, unless you plan to only ever have no more than 10 total entities. Buckets are not made to organize data like that: they are meant to store a variety of different types of data.

**Second**: do you *really* want to get *all* data from a bucket? That seems like a very uncommon use case. It's almost like asking "how do I query all data from all tables in a relational database"

That being said, I could imagine a very specialized situation where you'd want to do this. So, you could:

- Create a PRIMARY index and execute a [N1QL query](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/current/getting-started/try-a-query.html) like `SELECT * FROM mybucket;`
- Create a very simple [map/reduce view index](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/current/sdk/java/view-queries-with-sdk.html) of the data.

Both of these things can be done with the [Java SDK](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/current/sdk/java/start-using-sdk.html).

Comment: Thanks for answer, Matthew! As I understood from you answer it is better to store all data in one bucket and create indexes to track meta data of documents.

Comment: Yes, that's a good strategy. You can use a "type" field or similar to separate the documents, or give documents meaningful keys, or both.

Comment: @MatthewGroves, I edited your post (without changing it) just because I accidentally downvoted your post. This was the only way that let me change my vote.